# How can I be able to controlling the blur amount in macOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am able to control the blur amount in iOS with help of `fractionComplete` then I am trying to do same work in macOS native app, I made a multi platform project which run for iOS and native macOS, the codes are in below, the version of iOS works just fine and looking to reach same effect of controlling the amount of blur in macOS, but unable to find a property works as `fractionComplete` in macOS version.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(Font.system(size: 50.0))
                .padding()
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .fixedSize()
            
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(Font.system(size: 25.0))
                .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                .padding(20)
                .background(UnicornView())
                .border(Color.blue)
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
#if os(iOS)
struct UnicornView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    class UnicornControllerModel: UIViewController {
        
        var animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear)
        var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: nil)
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            
            super.viewDidLoad()

            animator.addAnimations {
                self.visualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)
            }
            animator.fractionComplete = 0.2
            view = visualEffectView
        }
        
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UnicornView>) -> UnicornControllerModel {
        return UnicornControllerModel()
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UnicornControllerModel, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<UnicornView>) {
    }
    
}
#endif
```

---

```
#if os(macOS)
struct UnicornView: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    class UnicornControllerModel: NSViewController {
        
        var animator = NSAnimation(duration: 1, animationCurve: .linear)
        var visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView()
        
        init() {
            super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        }
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            visualEffectView.material = .popover
            visualEffectView.blendingMode = .withinWindow
            view = visualEffectView
        }
        override func loadView() {
            view = NSView()
        }
        
    }
    
    func makeNSViewController(context: NSViewControllerRepresentableContext<UnicornView>) -> UnicornControllerModel {
        return UnicornControllerModel()
    }
    
    func updateNSViewController(_ nsViewController: UnicornControllerModel, context: NSViewControllerRepresentableContext<UnicornView>) {
    }
    
}
#endif
```

Comment: NSAnimation.currentProgress?

Comment: It seems that should what I need but in macOS, I cannot find `.addAnimations` either! So if I set `currentProgress` like `animator.currentProgress = 0.2` then how i should apply it in macOS version?